# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

While trying to uninstall `php7.0`, I got the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'php7.0' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-92 linux-headers-4.4.0-92-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-93 linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-96
  linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-92-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-93-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-96-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php:
 libapache2-mod-php depends on libapache2-mod-php7.0; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
 libapache2-mod-php
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I used the following command:

`sudo apt-get remove php7.0`

I searched the whole internet and tried all the solutions but did not got the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly because some package or dependency got stuck in package manager.

Try the following commands (with `sudo`):

```
apt-get purge
apt-get --autoremove
apt-get --autoclean
```

Then try uninstalling `php7.0` using the following command:

```
apt-get --purge remove php7.0
```

Comment: Not working still the same error is displaying when above command is run

Comment: @YatharthaJoshi It seems that the error is related to libapache php module. try disabling and purging that too

Comment: @YatharthaJoshi Anytime